# Short antonym for 'professional'

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I am considering a social media account for updates that are personal, chatty, opinionated, and specific to my geographic location. That is to say, not career-oriented or professional.

I need a term that describes this idea. I will use it to qualify my normal account name. The term needs to be short (say 6 letters or less). I am drawn to 'hyperlocal' but it is too long.

I'm happy to entertain poetic ideas (e.g. 'garden', 'backyard', etc).

Comment: I accept the verdict of 'too localized' but I invite comments on how I can rescue this question.

Answer (score 4):

My preference would be "casual."

Answer (score 2):

"Personal", "Domestic" or "Downtime" spring to mind, although "home" might be best.

Answer (score 2):

Your criteria, though not inconsistent, will still be hard to collect all together in one short word. 'Local' will be particularly difficult to get with the others. Despite that, I can offer:

- amateur: the primary direct antonym of professional
- informal: immediately chatty, personal, opinionated.
- relaxed: about the same as 'informal' in this context

Comment: Point-taken, though I'm trying to capture the spirit rather than list the criteria. Thanks for the reply. You've given me some other ideas: 'casual' and 'bluejeans'/'jeans'.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go for "hobbyist", "amateur", or "dabbler", maybe "beginner", as antonyms to "professional".

Comment: Or "unprofessional" as a different class of antonym.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I don't see Unprofessional as the antonym to professional. Unprofessional is someone who is expected to act professionally, but doesn't. A hobbyist/amateur is someone who doesn't act professionally, but you don't expect him to, either.

Comment: Not *the* antonym, *a* antonym. *Professional* can be used in different ways: when used as a noun *amateur* and friends are the only antonyms I can think of, but when used as an adjective it could be in opposition to *amateur*, *unprofessional*, *personal*, perhaps others.

Answer (score 1):

Thinking way outside the box, something like
from me
just me
my say
homebase
at home

Answer (score 1):

"Citizen" is clearly individual (as opposed to business), and does imply personal opinions. Citizens also form (local) communities.

Answer (score 1):

*[Jots](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/jot)*, "brief and hurriedly written notes" might convey the informal or casual tone you want.  Or perhaps *ideas, notions, abuzz*.

Appending a short word to your usual account name overly narrows what you can do.  Starting with a blank slate would let you play off your name or location.  Using neologisms would let you convey "personal, chatty, opinionated" by spelling or word choice (*e.g. dreems, idees, thots*).  For "specific to my geographic location" criterion, use or misuse a regional name or let an account picture, slogan, or radar map communicate that bit.